# Anyone got LunarEclipse to work with Eclipse 3.4.1?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lua

I spent a couple of hours yesterday trying to get LunarEclipse to work with Eclipse 3.4.1 and DLTK 1.0

I looked at some bug reports at [their sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lunareclipse) and they said that their 1.2.9 version was supposed to work with DLTK1.0. Problem being they hadn't actually released the 1.2.9 yet. You could get it at their SVN repository though.

I downloaded their svn repository. To my dismay I could not for the life of me remove all errors from the project. It kept saying it couldn't resolve **org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor** even though I added the org.eclipse.core.runtime external .jar file.

I guess the 1.2.9 isn't quite finished yet. So I wondered if anyone had some tips on what to do. Maybe I should just get an older version of eclipse and DLTK.

I have checked out LuaEclipse, but that didn't work either.

Summary:

- Have anyone gotten LunarEclipse to work with eclipse 3.4.1?
- Can you recommend any other Lua IDE or plugin for eclipse?

Comment: Coding Eclipse Plugins is ~50% black magic. Occasionally a jar isn't really the jar you need, which might explain the missing IProgressMonitor thing. Fiddling about with the target platform options sometimes helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beta release of LuaEclipse 1.3.0 does work for me and it is quite stable (except for the debugger plugin).

Grab it here:

http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/preview/update-site

Comment: Thanks, I just installed LuaEclipse 1.3.1 seems to work fine.