# What's a good Lua IDE for linux?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, lua

I'm looking for a lua IDE on linux.  The majority of suggestions I've seen so far are windows only.

I would have liked to use one of the Eclipse plugins for lua, but both of them -- LuaEclipse and LunarEclipse -- haven't been updated in nearly two years, and don't seem to work with Eclipse 3.5.  If you have had any luck in getting lua working in Eclipse, I would be very interested.

Comment: In Windows, I just used notepad. Lua's duck typing and relatively light syntax makes it perfectly possible to write substantial Lua programs with a simple text editor.

Comment: I created an IntelliJ plugin to support Lua. Check out my bitbucket page for screenshots and screencasts if you are interested. https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home

Comment: 1K views, the question was answered, and this was closed? Perhaps you could have just changed the title to "how to get LuaEclipse working in 3.5.

Comment: You can try [ZeroBrane Studio Lua IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/). Until recently it was Windows and OSX only, but the current version also supports Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701026/anyone-got-lunareclipse-to-work-with-eclipse-3-4-1) you could try the [beta site for LuaEclipse](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/preview/update-site/) and see if it works.

Comment: Ah, hadn't tried that site yet.  Still getting errors during installation on 3.5, though.

Answer (score 1):

LuaEclipse 1.2 and earlier does **not** work with newer Eclipses.

LuaEclipse 1.3 "beta" definitely **does** work with Eclipse 3.5 on Linux (at least on my Ubuntu box).

Grab it here: http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/preview/update-site

Also you may try LuaEclipse 2.0 beta (less stable): http://github.com/KINFOO/LuaEclipse/#readme

KDevelop also has some support for Lua (at least syntax highligting, which is enough in many cases).

Note also, that if you do not want an IDE, but merely an editor, you may use kate, gedit, SciTE and many other programmer's editors, available for Linux. Most of them support Lua out of the box (at least for syntax highlighting, some even have some rudimentary code completion).

Not to mention vim and emacs. :-)

Comment: FWIW, LuaEclipse 2.0 beta, mentioned in this answer, has now graduated into an official, and active, Eclipse project. It is available here http://eclipse.org/koneki/ldt.

Answer (score 0):

You might investigate [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html). Its available for both Windows and Linux, and is based on the Scintilla programmer's text editor component. It also supports scripting the editor in Lua, and can be used to debug Lua scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I use gedit with some plugins. That gives me syntax highlighting. I have a console in another window.

It would help to know what particular functionalities you need from your IDE, besides that.